# what is the output of this bitwise operation? and how?

Tags: bitwise-operators

```
int main()
{
   int a = '-' ^ '+';
   cout << a;
   return 0;
}
```

What is the output of this code? please explain  I know how xor works with numbers but using like this What is the output of this code and explain how?

Comment: Please, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the next time.

Comment: You can run it to find out the output.

Answer (score 1):

The '-' and '+' are chars (indicated by single quotes).

Chars are inheritly integers representing the characters place in ASCII.

'-' = 45, '+' = 43.

So your code is same as 45 ^ 43.

Internally they get converted to binary:

45 = 00101101 ,
43 = 00101011

and then the xor operation is performed on them resulting in

000110

and is then turned back to int (110 binary = 6 in decimal) and assigned to integer a.

Testing this in c:

```
 int a = '-' ^ '+';
 printf("%d", a); //%d is to print it as a number
```

Gave the result 6, exactly like my explanation did.